# If $\cos\theta=\frac{\cos\alpha+\cos \beta}{1+\cos\alpha\cos\beta}$, then prove that one value of $\tan(\theta/2)$ is $\tan(\alpha/2)\tan(\beta/2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If $$\cos\theta = \frac{\cos\alpha + \cos \beta}{1 + \cos\alpha\cos\beta}$$ then prove that one of the values of $\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ is $\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}$.

I don't even know how to start this question. Pls help

Comment: If you can write $\sin(\theta/2)$ and $\cos(\theta/2)$ in terms of $\cos\theta$, then you can write $\tan(\theta/2)$ in terms of $\cos\theta$.

Comment: Maybe this will help? $\tan(\theta/2)=\frac {1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac {\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-that-cos-1-cos-a-cos-b-1-cos-a-cos-b-2-tan-1-tan-a-2-tan-b-2

Comment: Use https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i have found out how to approach it. I hope this proof is satifactory.

Using the half angle formula, 
$$\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta}} \longrightarrow \text{eq.1}$$
Evaluating $\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta}$ first, 
$$\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta} = \frac{1 - (\frac{\cos\alpha + \cos\beta}{1 + \cos\alpha\cos\beta})}{1 + (\frac{\cos\alpha + \cos\beta}{1 + \cos\alpha\cos\beta})}\text{   }[\text{since } \cos\theta= \frac{\cos\alpha +\cos\beta}{1 + \cos\alpha\cos\beta}]$$
$$=\frac{1+\cos\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha -\cos\beta}{1+\cos\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha+ \cos\beta}$$
$$=\frac{(1-\cos\alpha)(1-\cos\beta)}{(1+\cos\alpha)(1+\cos\beta)}$$

Substituting this value of $\frac{1 - \cos\theta}{1 + \cos\theta}$ into equation 1,
$$\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos\alpha)(1-\cos\beta)}{(1+\cos\alpha)(1+\cos\beta)}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos\alpha)^2(1-\cos\beta)^2}{(1-\cos^2\alpha)(1-\cos^2\beta)}}$$
$$=\pm\frac{(1-\cos\alpha)(1-\cos\beta)}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}$$
Taking the positive value of $\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$,
$$\frac{(1-\cos\alpha)(1-\cos\beta)}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta} = \frac{4\sin^2\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin^2\frac{\beta}{2}}{4\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sin{\frac{\beta}{2}}\cos{\frac{\beta}{2}}} \text{(using half angle and double angle formula)}$$
$$=\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}$$

Therefore, $\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}$ is one of the values of $\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$.